# Echo ~/.bashrc PATH from a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc

I have `mybashscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -i

alias brc='source ~/.bashrc'

source /usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp
#exec bash
echo "******************pathhhhhhhh************"
echo $PATH
echo "******************pathhhhhhhh************"
/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp
```

This is the output when I run `./mybashscript.sh`:

```
bash: /bin/realbin/myapp: No such file or directory
******************pathhhhhhhh************
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
******************pathhhhhhhh************
/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp: 3: /usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp: /bin/realbin/myapp: not found
```

I wonder why `$PATH` of `~/.bashrc` is not appearing? also `myapp` is not found although if I run it from a normal terminal window by writing `myapp` since its path is included in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Path isn't defined in .bashrc but in my phone and don't have location off too of my head

Comment: The real problem could be line #3  of `/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp`